# Cloudflare worker generate smime signature

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, webcrypto-api, cloudflare-workers

Generating smime (CMS) signature with node-forge working good on Cloudflare Worker Editor, but When I deploy the code, I'm getting CPU Timeout (Error 1102).
So, I assume, when I call `signature.sign({ detached: true });`, it just taking time to generate signature.
I'm using `Business: 50ms`.

So,

1. Is it possible to increase node-forge process by setting any properties?
2. Is there any other alternative other then node-forge which I can use (expecting some example, I studies pkijs)

Looking for guide line.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, cryptographic algorithms implemented in pure JavaScript are likely to run very slowly and exceed the current CPU time limits imposed by Workers.

Instead, try using the WebCrypto API. Workers supports some of WebCrypto, and in particular it supports generating signatures in `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` format. Based on a quick Google search it looks like this may be what you need for S/MIME.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare has added [WebCrypto](https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-examples) to the workers recently. You really dont want to use JS crypto, Forge is full of it, see [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) for why.

If what you want is a pure crypto signature you don't even need PKIjs, just use it [directly](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples)

If you really want S/MIME a look at [PKIjs](http://pkijs.org) and use WebCrypto. the [S/MIME examples](https://pkijs.org/examples/SMIMEexample.html).